# why I am getting two different IP address in windows(main OS) and the Linux (In virtual box)

Tags: virtual-machine, ip, ifconfig

I am getting two different IP address in windows(main OS) and the Linux (In virtual box)[image]

Comment: When you got to virtualbox → devices → network →network-settings → attached to, what does it say?

Answer (score 3):

The Linux running within the VirtualBox is probably connected to the Internet via VirtualBox's own software network interface which provides NAT (this is a setting in VirtualBox).

Think of it as a having a router with a DHCP server running beside your Linux machine.  The router gives the Linux machine an IP address in the `10.x.x.x` range and all traffic goes through it to reach the outside world. The "outside world" includes your Windows machine and the rest of the Internet.

Comment: Even if it were bridged... the virtual NIC will has a different virtual MAC, and in what  respects the network, is as if it were a different NIC.